# Why do I see project directory name instead of dotnet(out-of-process) while running ASP.NET Core app through dotnet CLI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a sample ASP.NET Core app with the name **EmployeeManagement**. The app is configured explicitly for **out-of-process** hosting as below,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The primary goal of this application is to display current running process name.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
   endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
   {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
   });
  });
}
```

And when I run the application using dotnet CLI, it displays

> EmployeeManagement

Why it does not display **dotnet** as process name? As we are running the application using **dotnet CLI**, application might be hosted and running in **Kestrel** server. So, I assume **dotnet.exe** should be the hosting process.

If the application is configured for **InProcess** hosting model. it displays

> iisexpress

as process name. The target framework is **.NET Core 3.1** version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0 a host exe ("apphost") is generated automatically for the platform you're currently building on (except for macOS due to its signing/notarization requirements), so the `EmployeeManagement.exe` in your bin folder will be used to run the .NET Core Runtime.

You should see a difference if you directly use `dotnet bin\netcoreapp3.1\EmployeeManagement.dll` or set the following in the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseAppHost>False</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```